# uncaught referenceerror: table is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting this error message when trying to create a table using the Google Visualization API, with PHP & MySQL in the background.

- db connection is OK
- creating JSON from PHP array is OK
- JSON format is OK

This is the error I get: **uncaught referenceerror: table is not defined**

```
 <!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 // Load the Visualization API and the table package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['table']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  function drawTable() {
        var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(
        <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);
    var options = {
      title: 'A Station'
    };
    var table_draw = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table_draw.draw(tdata, options);
  }
```

Comment: what this has anything to do with __php__ and __mysql__?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use a variable, `table`, which you have never defined.

Possibly you wanted to use the variable `table_draw` which you have defined in the line before.

```
var table_draw = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
table_draw.draw(tdata, options);
```